# Iterate elements on multiple python lists

Tags: python, iteration

How can I achieve to iterate multiple lists in the most pythonic way?

Say I have 2 lists:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [4, 5, 6]
```

How can I achieve the iteration over the whole set of elements in l1 and l2 without altering l1 and l2?

I can simply join both lists and then iterate over the result:

```
l3 = l1[:]
l3.extend(l2)
for e in l3:
  # ... whatever with e
```

But that solution does not sounds to me as very pythonic, nor efficient, so I'm looking for a better way.

Comment: You can always just iterate `l1`, then iterate `l2`, in separate loops. If there's too much code in the loops to be worth repeating, just abstract it into a function. However, that being said, `chain` is almost always the best answer, as F.J suggests. For example, if you wanted to use a genexpr or listcomp or function instead of an explicit loop, you can't just break it into two genexprs. (Well, you _can_… but only by calling `chain` on the result, so you might as well just `chain` at the start…)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly iterate over `l1 + l2`:

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l2 = [4, 5, 6]
>>> 
>>> for e in l1 + l2:
...     print e
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`itertools.chain()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
import itertools
for e in itertools.chain(l1, l2):
    print e
```

This doesn't need to create a temporary list for the iteration, unlike `l1 + l2`.  It will also work for arbitrary iterables and for sequences of different types.  For example:

```
>>> l1 = (1, 2, 3)
>>> l2 = [4, 5, 6]
>>> l1 + l2        # can't loop over l1 + l2...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple
>>> import itertools
>>> for e in itertools.chain(l1, l2):
...     print e
...
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: This is the most Pythonic approach, +1

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think I have to stop asking for pythonic solutions. I recognize your answer is the pythoniest one, but the one I was looking for is the other one by Rohit Jain. Hummm as I said, I have to stop asking for pythonics, but again thanks. (And it wasn't me who downvoted eh? moreover, I upvoted you :D )

Answer (score 1):

Use the list concatenation operator, `+` (i.e, `l1 + l2`) and iterate over that.